# Difference between sizeof(&vector[0]) and vector.size()

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

From what I understand, the C function sizeof(), when given an array, returns the size in bytes of allocated memory to the array. That is, for a declaration `unsigned char my_array[10];`, `sizeof(my_array);` will return 10.

In C++, `vector::size()` similarly returns the number of elements in the vector. In the case of `std::vector<unsigned char>`, the number of elements in the vector should theoretically match the number of bytes in the underlying array.

Now, the source of the confusion: I have read that `&vector[0]` returns the underlying array from a vector. As such, I would *expect* that `sizeof(&vector[0])` would return the number of elements in the array, if vector were of type `std::vector<unsigned int>`.

However, I tested this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    std::vector<unsigned char> test_vector;
    test_vector.resize(1024);
    
    unsigned char test_array[1024];

    std::cout << sizeof(test_array) << '\n';
    std::cout << test_vector.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(&test_vector[0]) << '\n';

}
```

And it outputs:

```
1024
1024
8
```

Why is the behavior of `test_vector.size()` and `sizeof(&test_vector[0])` different, and where does 8 come from?

Comment: Hint: `&test_vector[0]` gives you a pointer

Comment: `sizeof` isn't a function. It's an operator that takes any expression and returns the size of the **type** of that expression relative to the size of `char`.

Comment: _"I have read that `&vector[0]` returns the underlying array"_.  It does not.  It produces a pointer to `vector[0]`.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Is an array a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: FYI, if you really want to get a pointer to `std::vector`'s underlying storage, using [`std::vector::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) is more clear.

Comment: @Drew Agreed. I also found another complementary duplicate. Feel free to suggest others.

Comment: @DrewDormann Okay, that clears things up a bit. Is there a way, then, to retrieve the underlying array, as opposed to a pointer to the first element? I know vector::data() returns a pointer to the first element of the array, also.

Comment: @HUNTERCROSLAND There is no 'underlying array' - in terms of something like a *declared* array. The vector has a *pointer* as one of its internal members, and that points to dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @AdrianMole Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!